# If exists any nested key wirh value

Tags: typescript

Having an JSON-object like:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Object1": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object3": {
        "Type": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

How would one check if there is any type that has the value "bar"?

I am looking for a method that allows any nesting depth of the objects. So also:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Object3": {
        "Nested": {
            "Type": "bar"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Should trigger a true result.

Comment: Iterate over the Resources object and check for each key if it has a Type field and if that equals bar (assuming the example you provided is not more complicated)?

Comment: @tomerpacific I am more looking into a method that will allow any nesting depth. I will edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: This is a great candidate for a recursive function that compare the values to the expected value and if it's an object or array, call itself again with the subobject as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the key-value pairs (entries) of the object — recursively, if the object has nested object values — and compare them to your target values. This strategy is efficient because it avoids iterating the entire object (or nested objects) in the case that a matching entry is found before reaching the end of the object — it will return `true` as soon as the first match is found:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsATgSwgZwDwBUoQB7ARwAmaUA9gEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3gFBRQDaA0lGRwoAawghyAMyhYAugC4+-ADSyBcuQG5OAX17jJM+Ts5SArnAbJycAFRDCiAIaF4SVJhz5CJMlVoGRgAKbgoaJSwVTgBKJQBxIggXYHJEDHcUdGxGNQA3cmRiZi4eKTSoYLpbNGAxCSERAJiOMJ5kGWCAeRp6YAA6AAtnNC6AdzhggLVDGJbSnkWQVAAbYj5DNQCDCU0dRahdMKOjs0trWyhhtEyQUJ4ApQC+6J5DJQAFRHJIRFB+CSvKB5ZwrcwQJSWURwcgTaJxKCUcjkFYQZwiBblRCVNpQapwWobfJyCgyZBOVwQTKeKY0FojXE8ACSFMoqIwvC+P2S-0BUChMImckYYXmuI6OIOPGColYLDYhigADIlcC5WwQWCIC0AD46xmSqU8UCQaRq+VsABEzwYluVSoNPDyUAAhPKoHBzCsVvbHVcRrdgnkZnzNeCYgaIwcWogIMBzIgREhwftDmFY-HE1ApKC0BAdKcAPSFqAATXICdweGcAFswKjgaDwWgFJx8YThGBzMAyGxeGF2FBi41iPgoAAGXEAJXQFcQdHQSgWBx6gWAAEYl7JwBCoJbyuQ7bogSvegwAExbrA7pT75FHk+LVd9ADMV5ve8ozkQD9xx+OQKDsOwijngUDrtOs4JguLatEaz4MG+cFGlAABy6CEMQS5+jw16QLeX4-o+Bz-kapGLOR-7aJwZgVFUNR1LwIH4GonbdiSZpsT2-REB46DBHMyHtiiED9Cs5AAObBMxeBqNcgZcWolp4RAlpKYRlpzAWQ52JwXTdl2wCtgAtBOUDJhAnCmeu5mIOCnB2IWnBAA)

```ts
type Entries<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]];
}[keyof T];

function* iterateEntries<T extends object>(
  obj: T,
): Generator<Entries<T>, void> {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(obj, key)) {
      yield [key, obj[key]];
    }
  }
}

function hasEntry(
  obj: object,
  key: PropertyKey,
  value: unknown,
): boolean {
  for (
    const [k, v] of iterateEntries(obj) as
      Iterable<[PropertyKey, unknown]>
  ) {
    if (
      (k === key && v === value) ||
      (
        typeof v === "object" &&
        v !== null &&
        hasEntry(v, key, value)
      )
    ) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

// Your example values:
const inputs = [
  { // index 0
    Resources: {
      Object1: { Type: "foo" },
      Object2: { Type: "foo" },
      Object3: { Type: "bar" },
    },
  },
  { // index 1
    Resources: {
      Object3: {
        Nested: {
          Type: "bar",
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

for (const [index, input] of inputs.entries()) {
  console.log(index, hasEntry(input, "Type", "bar"));
} /*
Output:
- 0 true
- 1 true
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterating Over each object may results in recursive function and that kind of errors. if u want to check it just stringify using JSON.stringify(myobject) and if it contains ""Type": "bar"" . irrespectve of how nested ur object is it can function .& U can loop over this string characters to find how many type:bar is there inside.

```js
const mystring = JSON.stringify(myobject);
if (mystring.includes('"Type":"bar"')) {
  console.log("Type Bar Found");
}
```

Comment: This is a neat solution that would work in my specific use case and which I completely overlooked. However because the question insinuated that it should work with an object I accepted an other answer that also answered the question as the correct answer.

Comment: This is a clever idea (conceptually)! In practice, there are quite a few edge cases that would cause either a false negative result, or  cause an exception to be thrown (many types of objects can't be serialized using `JSON.stringify` — for example: `const obj = {}; obj.foo = obj; JSON.stringify(obj);` will cause a `TypeError` to the thrown).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a JS question than a TS question, but since you tagged it that way, let's add some type safety to this. :)

Updating the interfaces defined should guide you to other checks that may need to be implemented (e.g. If data objects can also contain other keys that have number values, etc.)

```
// Adding some types, assuming that the JSON data is coming from // Adding some types, assuming that the JSON data is coming from elsewhere
interface DataObject {
  Type: string
  [name: string]: DataObject | string
}

interface ResourcesData {
  Resources: { [name: string]: DataObject }
}

const data1 = {
  "Resources": {
    "Object1": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
  }
};

const data2 = {
  "Resources": {
    "Object1": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Type": "bar"
    },
  }
};

const data3 = {
  "Resources": {
    "Object1": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Type": "foo",
        "Nested": {
            "Type": "bar"
        }
    },
    "Object3": {
        "Type": "foo"
    }
  }
};

const data4 = {
  "Resources": {
    "Object1": {
        "Type": "foo"
    },
    "Object2": {
        "Type": "foo",
        "Nested": {
            "Type": "foo",
            "Nested": {
                "Type": "foo",
                "Nested": {
                    "Type": "foo",
                    "Nested": {
                        "Type": "bar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Object3": {
        "Type": "foo"
    }
  }
};

function objHasType(obj: DataObject, objType: string): boolean {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .some(([key, value]) => {
            if (typeof value === 'string') {
                return key === 'Type' && value === objType;
            } else {
                return objHasType(value, objType);
            }
        });
};

const resourcesHaveType = (data: ResourcesData, objType: string) => {
    return Object.entries(data.Resources)
        .some(([_, obj]) => objHasType(obj, objType));
}

console.log(resourcesHaveType(data1, 'bar'));
console.log(resourcesHaveType(data2, 'bar'));
console.log(resourcesHaveType(data3, 'bar'));
console.log(resourcesHaveType(data4, 'bar'));
```

[interactive Typescript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBNISwOwOagM4HsC2BTUAXAngA6bIA0oAhssgK7rxI4AW5Ouj2AUgMoDyAcqEgtyoGMlABjDPVAAzAE4ZQmADbJMAd3bzMAKHg5M82eQnYAIsJ4AjAFaYJrAN67QoACqFMALhQ559K6gANpw5Fi+yP70ALq+ljjkNvaOoAA+fgGIugC+uvpwhsam2ABKxKjU8mbICSIubuVoVTW+TiFhEZmx8VZ2Dqx5ebpScFGCwgCMoAC8oA2gAERNldXEi21BbovJA5Mb81tux4ueRAeLsqioi0c5JEc7-Y4ATAcLxydnmBdXN3cPNxDADc+VG4yEiRes0O2xWLXWm0+TxSOH2SM+Xy8v2ut0+90eu1e7yOyO+F2s5HkeOOBKBuVBI1QY1YkPIAGYYQtlhUEcgSciiWiBZjtuTfJdcQDCc8cG8MaLTtiJX9FoDRUs+MRDJARRqsecJZTqaTadLBbL2XrMUrDUtVXcgiCwcyIcIACxcoI85prfkKpZC9GwjW2n4qqX49XbIXykOK8X23HRm1aqKYXUB-VhnE3FPZtM6636snKpN500lzXajPFqs2xOSiv1kuLQu1rMt0ON400ruYvL9+ktwca0dAlMogZWztistNvugUfO3SyahwRwwZmgVB2AASlG+AApd7ZeokhWRT99ItFEABKXzWa4qTDkODx0A6HBVD9CgB0mCFAExAnnY96VqA-5oFgR5HsEADWmB4GQABu5AqNQmAxPeswAHyfvqMCyKAR74EQqAkehmHYDMdGgAA5FEWQIAxuEfF236-qASF4LM9EMd8DGgAAZCJoDUVh-FzNeXigiOyhqNgHEtlx8gfqeB7IMekmYFedjfPe8n1uOA5GQyLosl+vJ+geqGYN8MJHmyvjwn6dT6bYN7dA++Gfmpf6yoBwEwKBbL-m5NQQfq0EYJgcHBAA+p5OF+Zph5eGBtieYZ5nDOCqCvv+KioAgR46L6NR2Q5mVspMZAMcabHmQVRUlWVFWrFV5D2cebIvA1TX3i1rqFZgxWleVNndb1tXCOyg1Us1oKteN7VTZVxDVX1HqLfIy1AA)